# bash file Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash

I don't know why my bash file in Linux Ubuntu doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash`   
echo -n "Write user name : "
read NAME
cd
if grep -c "$NAME" /etc/passwd -eq 0; then
  echo "$NAME doesn't esist"
else
  echo "$NAME already esist"
fi`
```

It gives the error:

```
$ bash ./name.sh 
Write user name : root
grep: root: No such file or directory
/etc/passwd:3
grep: 0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What do you think it should do? What does it actually do? Define "doesn't work"

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `-q` option of grep.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2):

The code is not executing the grep in a sub-shell, and the if-condition needs to be wrapped in square brackets.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Write user name : "
read NAME
cd
if [ `grep -c "$NAME" /etc/passwd` -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "$NAME doesn't esist"
else
  echo "$NAME" already esist
fi
```

Output:

```
$ bash ./name.sh
Write user name : root
root already esist
$ bash ./name.sh
Write user name : ddd
ddd doesn't esist
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some strange backquotes in your script which you should remove

```
#!/bin/bash   
read -p "Write user name : " name
if grep -q "$name" /etc/passwd; then
  echo "$name already exists"
else
  echo "$name doesn't exist"
fi
```

as you can see

- read can show a prompt
- variables should be lowercase
- the exit value of `grep` determines the case and no need for parenthesis or brackets
- also notice that is looking for `name` everywhere, not just user names

because you included the shebang you can

```
$ chmod +x script
$ ./script
```

Comment: Thank you it works.